# bind udp server to external ip via port forwarding

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, remote-access, lan

Is it possible to connect a udp socket to an external ip after port forwarding is done?

```
var PORT = 33333;
var HOST = 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx'; // my external ip

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + 
address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + 
message);

});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

port forwarding already set up (below)

[image: any source forwards to 127.0.0.1:33333]

I'm getting 'EADDRNOTAVAIL' error

```
Error: bind EADDRNOTAVAIL xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:33333
```

Is this even possible? and if not, what are my options for listening in to remote ip addresses?

Thank
Asaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind to a non-local address, and you don't need to. Just bind to 0.0.0.0. The port forwarding will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `var HOST = '0.0.0.0';` for connecting outside your host?