# Port Forwarded Python Socket Error (SERVER)

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I am currently working on a **Python** project to control my PC remotely from across networks. Currently I have a portmap.io connection set up, (IP: 193.xxx.xxx.xx with port 1234, I’m using an OpenVPN)
When I run my Python script:

```
import socket
from os import system, name
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
HOST = “193.xxx.xxx.xx”
PORT = 1234
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
s.send(b”Connection established”.encode(“utf-8”))
```

When I run this Python script, I get this error:

> OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

I’m almost 85% sure this is because you can’t use bind() on an ip, so what should I do? The socket needs to go across networks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bind udp server to external ip via port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731376/bind-udp-server-to-external-ip-via-port-forwarding). To cite form the answer *"You can't bind to a non-local address, and you don't need to. Just bind to 0.0.0.0. The port forwarding will do the rest."*.

Answer (score 0):

(SOLVED)
I used ngrok to create a tcp tunnel and used 0.0.0.0 as my local host, and used the provided details for the remote connection